# google custom search add annotation programmatically

Tags: google-search-api

when adding annotation programatically ,refer to http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/docs/api.html#create_annos  , can i assign "id" to each annotation so later on, when i need to delete it i can just delete by the id instead of required to retrieve all the annotation and delete it?

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to describes how this works:

> The XML for removing annotations is
>   slightly different. Instead of using
>   the full annotation format with URL
>   and label names, you just need to use
>   the annotations ID or href id. Custom
>   Search tags each annotation with an
>   href id. To get this ID, retrieve all
>   the annotations and extract the href
>   id of the annotations you want to
>   delete.
>
> The following is a code snippet that
>   removes annotations.

```
  <Remove>
     <Annotations>
       <Annotation href="Cg93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8Qrsq3gv456gRI" />
       <Annotation href="Cg93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8Qzsq3gvWd23" />
     </Annotations>
  </Remove>
```

In other words, no, you cannot assign your own ID to an annotation; you have to retrieve the list of existing annotations to find the ID of the element(s) you want to remove.